# Admob Mediation

Tags: iphone, admob, xcode4.3

In one of my application i need to show custom interstitial ad through admob mediation.
I am using AdMarvel for getting my custom event interstitial ad.
I have a class which creates admarvel interstitial ad and sends it to admob mediation.

In my custom class, i get these delegates called:

```
- (void)getInterstitialAdSucceeded
{
  [self.delegate customEventInterstitial:self didReceiveAd:adMarvelView];
}
```

After this, i get below delegate method called. In this i am trying to display the interstitial ad like below:

```
- (void)presentFromRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
   [adMarvelView displayInterstitial];
}
```

But app is not showing any interstitial ad. Am i missing anything?
Kindly let me know.

Comment: Did you end up fixing this? Does showing AdMarvel banner ads work for you with AdMob mediation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to add self as rootViewController for adMarvelView. Then this will work.